# java.lang.NumberFormatException - Oracle ADF Java managed bean

Tags: java, oracle, oracle-adf, managed-bean

I have the following code written in a managed bean, method saveData(ActionEvent actionEvent) is attached to a button action so when the button pressed the saveData method will execute .....

```
    public BindingContainer getBindingsCont() {
    return BindingContext.getCurrent().getCurrentBindingsEntry();
}
public void saveData(ActionEvent actionEvent) {
    //Get Binding Continer of Page
            BindingContainer bc = this.getBindingsCont();
         //Get shuttle binding from pagedef
            JUCtrlListBinding listBindings = (JUCtrlListBinding)bc.get("AvailableCourses");
        //Get Selected Values
            Object str[] = listBindings.getSelectedValues();
        //Iterate over selected values
            for (int i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
                System.out.println(str[i]);
            }
}
```

and this code should fetch the id of selected courses from a shuttle component
but when i click the button i get the following error

```
<oracle.adf.controller> <ControlFlowEngine> <checkForBadState> <ADFc: During exception handling the view port page flow stack was popped to find an application handler but the displayed view was not updated.  The view is now likely in an invalid state, viewId=/WEB-INF/home.xml#home@AvailableCourses.> 
<oracle.dfw.impl.incident.DiagnosticsDataExtractorImpl> <DiagnosticsDataExtractorImpl> <createADRIncident> <incident flood controlled with Problem Key "ADFC-00032 [ADFc]"> 
<oracle.adf.view> <RichExceptionHandler> <_logUnhandledException> <ADF_FACES-60098:Faces lifecycle receives unhandled exceptions in phase PROCESS_VALIDATIONS 3> 
oracle.jbo.domain.DataCreationException: JBO-25009: Cannot create an object of type:java.lang.Integer from type:java.lang.String with value:Data-Structure 1
    at oracle.jbo.common.JboTypeMapEntries$1.convert(JboTypeMapEntries.java:124)
    at oracle.jbo.domain.TypeFactory.get(TypeFactory.java:892)
    at oracle.jbo.domain.TypeFactory.getInstance(TypeFactory.java:120)
    at oracle.jbo.domain.TypeFactory.convertToPrimitiveArray(TypeFactory.java:977)
    at oracle.jbo.domain.TypeFactory.get(TypeFactory.java:904)
    at oracle.jbo.domain.TypeFactory.getInstance(TypeFactory.java:120)
    at oracle.jbo.uicli.binding.JUCtrlListBinding.processNewInputValue(JUCtrlListBinding.java:4212)
    at oracle.adfinternal.view.faces.model.binding.FacesCtrlListBinding$ListValidator.validate(FacesCtrlListBinding.java:631)
    at oracle.adfinternal.view.faces.facelets.rich.JsfValidatorHandler$BindingValidator.validate(JsfValidatorHandler.java:122)
    at org.apache.myfaces.trinidad.component.UIXEditableValue.validateValue(UIXEditableValue.java:454)
    at org.apache.myfaces.trinidad.component.UIXSelectMany.validateValue(UIXSelectMany.java:95)
    at org.apache.myfaces.trinidad.component.UIXEditableValue.validate(UIXEditableValue.java:209)
    at org.apache.myfaces.trinidad.component.UIXEditableValue._executeValidate(UIXEditableValue.java:753)
    at org.apache.myfaces.trinidad.component.UIXEditableValue.processValidators(UIXEditableValue.java:349)
    at org.apache.myfaces.trinidad.component.UIXComponentBase.validateChildrenImpl(UIXComponentBase.java:1565)
    at org.apache.myfaces.trinidad.component.UIXComponentBase.validateChildren(UIXComponentBase.java:1550)
    at org.apache.myfaces.trinidad.component.UIXComponentBase.processValidators(UIXComponentBase.java:1307)
    at org.apache.myfaces.trinidad.component.UIXForm.processValidators(UIXForm.java:82)
    at oracle.adfinternal.view.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl$ProcessValidationsCallback.invokeContextCallback(LifecycleImpl.java:1681)
    at org.apache.myfaces.trinidad.component.UIXComponentBase.invokeOnComponent(UIXComponentBase.java:2183)
    at org.apache.myfaces.trinidad.component.UIXComponentBase.invokeOnChildrenComponents(UIXComponentBase.java:2069)
    at org.apache.myfaces.trinidad.component.UIXComponentBase.invokeOnComponent(UIXComponentBase.java:2199)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.invokeOnComponent(UIComponent.java:1503)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.invokeOnComponent(UIComponentBase.java:714)
    at oracle.adfinternal.view.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl._executeApplyValidateOrUpdate(LifecycleImpl.java:551)
    at oracle.adfinternal.view.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl._executePhase(LifecycleImpl.java:354)
    at oracle.adfinternal.view.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:224)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:650)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper$ServletServiceAction.run(StubSecurityHelper.java:286)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper$ServletServiceAction.run(StubSecurityHelper.java:260)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper.invokeServlet(StubSecurityHelper.java:137)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletStubImpl.execute(ServletStubImpl.java:350)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.TailFilter.doFilter(TailFilter.java:25)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:78)
    at oracle.adf.model.servlet.ADFBindingFilter.doFilter(ADFBindingFilter.java:194)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:78)
    at oracle.adfinternal.view.faces.webapp.rich.RegistrationFilter.doFilter(RegistrationFilter.java:105)
    at org.apache.myfaces.trinidadinternal.webapp.TrinidadFilterImpl$FilterListChain.doFilter(TrinidadFilterImpl.java:529)
    at oracle.adfinternal.view.faces.activedata.AdsFilter.doFilter(AdsFilter.java:60)
    at org.apache.myfaces.trinidadinternal.webapp.TrinidadFilterImpl$FilterListChain.doFilter(TrinidadFilterImpl.java:529)
    at org.apache.myfaces.trinidadinternal.webapp.TrinidadFilterImpl._doFilterImpl(TrinidadFilterImpl.java:354)
    at org.apache.myfaces.trinidadinternal.webapp.TrinidadFilterImpl.doFilter(TrinidadFilterImpl.java:232)
    at org.apache.myfaces.trinidad.webapp.TrinidadFilter.doFilter(TrinidadFilter.java:92)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:78)
    at oracle.security.jps.ee.http.JpsAbsFilter$1.run(JpsAbsFilter.java:141)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at oracle.security.jps.util.JpsSubject.doAsPrivileged(JpsSubject.java:315)
    at oracle.security.jps.ee.util.JpsPlatformUtil.runJaasMode(JpsPlatformUtil.java:649)
    at oracle.security.jps.ee.http.JpsAbsFilter.runJaasMode(JpsAbsFilter.java:124)
    at oracle.security.jps.ee.http.JpsAbsFilter.doFilter(JpsAbsFilter.java:232)
    at oracle.security.jps.ee.http.JpsFilter.doFilter(JpsFilter.java:94)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:78)
    at oracle.dms.servlet.DMSServletFilter.doFilter(DMSServletFilter.java:224)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:78)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.RequestEventsFilter.doFilter(RequestEventsFilter.java:32)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:78)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext$ServletInvocationAction.wrapRun(WebAppServletContext.java:3654)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext$ServletInvocationAction.run(WebAppServletContext.java:3620)
    at weblogic.security.acl.internal.AuthenticatedSubject.doAs(AuthenticatedSubject.java:326)
    at weblogic.security.service.SecurityManager.runAsForUserCode(SecurityManager.java:196)
    at weblogic.servlet.provider.WlsSecurityProvider.runAsForUserCode(WlsSecurityProvider.java:203)
    at weblogic.servlet.provider.WlsSubjectHandle.run(WlsSubjectHandle.java:71)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.doSecuredExecute(WebAppServletContext.java:2423)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.securedExecute(WebAppServletContext.java:2280)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.execute(WebAppServletContext.java:2258)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletRequestImpl.runInternal(ServletRequestImpl.java:1626)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletRequestImpl.run(ServletRequestImpl.java:1586)
    at weblogic.servlet.provider.ContainerSupportProviderImpl$WlsRequestExecutor.run(ContainerSupportProviderImpl.java:270)
    at weblogic.invocation.ComponentInvocationContextManager._runAs(ComponentInvocationContextManager.java:348)
    at weblogic.invocation.ComponentInvocationContextManager.runAs(ComponentInvocationContextManager.java:333)
    at weblogic.work.LivePartitionUtility.doRunWorkUnderContext(LivePartitionUtility.java:54)
    at weblogic.work.PartitionUtility.runWorkUnderContext(PartitionUtility.java:41)
    at weblogic.work.SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl.runWorkUnderContext(SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl.java:617)
    at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.execute(ExecuteThread.java:397)
    at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:346)
Caused by: java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "Data-Structure 1"
    at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:65)
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:580)
    at java.lang.Integer.valueOf(Integer.java:766)
    at oracle.jbo.common.JboTypeMapEntries$1.convert(JboTypeMapEntries.java:118)
    ... 74 more
## Detail 0 ##
java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "Data-Structure 1"
    at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:65)
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:580)
    at java.lang.Integer.valueOf(Integer.java:766)
    at oracle.jbo.common.JboTypeMapEntries$1.convert(JboTypeMapEntries.java:118)
    at oracle.jbo.domain.TypeFactory.get(TypeFactory.java:892)
    at oracle.jbo.domain.TypeFactory.getInstance(TypeFactory.java:120)
    at oracle.jbo.domain.TypeFactory.convertToPrimitiveArray(TypeFactory.java:977)
    at oracle.jbo.domain.TypeFactory.get(TypeFactory.java:904)
    at oracle.jbo.domain.TypeFactory.getInstance(TypeFactory.java:120)
    at oracle.jbo.uicli.binding.JUCtrlListBinding.processNewInputValue(JUCtrlListBinding.java:4212)
    at oracle.adfinternal.view.faces.model.binding.FacesCtrlListBinding$ListValidator.validate(FacesCtrlListBinding.java:631)
    at oracle.adfinternal.view.faces.facelets.rich.JsfValidatorHandler$BindingValidator.validate(JsfValidatorHandler.java:122)
    at org.apache.myfaces.trinidad.component.UIXEditableValue.validateValue(UIXEditableValue.java:454)
    at org.apache.myfaces.trinidad.component.UIXSelectMany.validateValue(UIXSelectMany.java:95)
    at org.apache.myfaces.trinidad.component.UIXEditableValue.validate(UIXEditableValue.java:209)
    at org.apache.myfaces.trinidad.component.UIXEditableValue._executeValidate(UIXEditableValue.java:753)
    at org.apache.myfaces.trinidad.component.UIXEditableValue.processValidators(UIXEditableValue.java:349)
    at org.apache.myfaces.trinidad.component.UIXComponentBase.validateChildrenImpl(UIXComponentBase.java:1565)
    at org.apache.myfaces.trinidad.component.UIXComponentBase.validateChildren(UIXComponentBase.java:1550)
    at org.apache.myfaces.trinidad.component.UIXComponentBase.processValidators(UIXComponentBase.java:1307)
    at org.apache.myfaces.trinidad.component.UIXForm.processValidators(UIXForm.java:82)
    at oracle.adfinternal.view.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl$ProcessValidationsCallback.invokeContextCallback(LifecycleImpl.java:1681)
    at org.apache.myfaces.trinidad.component.UIXComponentBase.invokeOnComponent(UIXComponentBase.java:2183)
    at org.apache.myfaces.trinidad.component.UIXComponentBase.invokeOnChildrenComponents(UIXComponentBase.java:2069)
    at org.apache.myfaces.trinidad.component.UIXComponentBase.invokeOnComponent(UIXComponentBase.java:2199)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.invokeOnComponent(UIComponent.java:1503)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.invokeOnComponent(UIComponentBase.java:714)
    at oracle.adfinternal.view.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl._executeApplyValidateOrUpdate(LifecycleImpl.java:551)
    at oracle.adfinternal.view.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl._executePhase(LifecycleImpl.java:354)
    at oracle.adfinternal.view.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:224)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:650)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper$ServletServiceAction.run(StubSecurityHelper.java:286)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper$ServletServiceAction.run(StubSecurityHelper.java:260)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper.invokeServlet(StubSecurityHelper.java:137)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletStubImpl.execute(ServletStubImpl.java:350)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.TailFilter.doFilter(TailFilter.java:25)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:78)
    at oracle.adf.model.servlet.ADFBindingFilter.doFilter(ADFBindingFilter.java:194)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:78)
    at oracle.adfinternal.view.faces.webapp.rich.RegistrationFilter.doFilter(RegistrationFilter.java:105)
    at org.apache.myfaces.trinidadinternal.webapp.TrinidadFilterImpl$FilterListChain.doFilter(TrinidadFilterImpl.java:529)
    at oracle.adfinternal.view.faces.activedata.AdsFilter.doFilter(AdsFilter.java:60)
    at org.apache.myfaces.trinidadinternal.webapp.TrinidadFilterImpl$FilterListChain.doFilter(TrinidadFilterImpl.java:529)
    at org.apache.myfaces.trinidadinternal.webapp.TrinidadFilterImpl._doFilterImpl(TrinidadFilterImpl.java:354)
    at org.apache.myfaces.trinidadinternal.webapp.TrinidadFilterImpl.doFilter(TrinidadFilterImpl.java:232)
    at org.apache.myfaces.trinidad.webapp.TrinidadFilter.doFilter(TrinidadFilter.java:92)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:78)
    at oracle.security.jps.ee.http.JpsAbsFilter$1.run(JpsAbsFilter.java:141)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at oracle.security.jps.util.JpsSubject.doAsPrivileged(JpsSubject.java:315)
    at oracle.security.jps.ee.util.JpsPlatformUtil.runJaasMode(JpsPlatformUtil.java:649)
    at oracle.security.jps.ee.http.JpsAbsFilter.runJaasMode(JpsAbsFilter.java:124)
    at oracle.security.jps.ee.http.JpsAbsFilter.doFilter(JpsAbsFilter.java:232)
    at oracle.security.jps.ee.http.JpsFilter.doFilter(JpsFilter.java:94)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:78)
    at oracle.dms.servlet.DMSServletFilter.doFilter(DMSServletFilter.java:224)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:78)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.RequestEventsFilter.doFilter(RequestEventsFilter.java:32)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:78)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext$ServletInvocationAction.wrapRun(WebAppServletContext.java:3654)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext$ServletInvocationAction.run(WebAppServletContext.java:3620)
    at weblogic.security.acl.internal.AuthenticatedSubject.doAs(AuthenticatedSubject.java:326)
    at weblogic.security.service.SecurityManager.runAsForUserCode(SecurityManager.java:196)
    at weblogic.servlet.provider.WlsSecurityProvider.runAsForUserCode(WlsSecurityProvider.java:203)
    at weblogic.servlet.provider.WlsSubjectHandle.run(WlsSubjectHandle.java:71)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.doSecuredExecute(WebAppServletContext.java:2423)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.securedExecute(WebAppServletContext.java:2280)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.execute(WebAppServletContext.java:2258)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletRequestImpl.runInternal(ServletRequestImpl.java:1626)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletRequestImpl.run(ServletRequestImpl.java:1586)
    at weblogic.servlet.provider.ContainerSupportProviderImpl$WlsRequestExecutor.run(ContainerSupportProviderImpl.java:270)
    at weblogic.invocation.ComponentInvocationContextManager._runAs(ComponentInvocationContextManager.java:348)
    at weblogic.invocation.ComponentInvocationContextManager.runAs(ComponentInvocationContextManager.java:333)
    at weblogic.work.LivePartitionUtility.doRunWorkUnderContext(LivePartitionUtility.java:54)
    at weblogic.work.PartitionUtility.runWorkUnderContext(PartitionUtility.java:41)
    at weblogic.work.SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl.runWorkUnderContext(SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl.java:617)
    at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.execute(ExecuteThread.java:397)
    at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:346)
<oracle.adf.view> <PartialResponseUtils> <handleError> <ADF_FACES-60096:Server Exception during PPR, #2> 
oracle.jbo.domain.DataCreationException: JBO-29114 ADFContext is not setup to process messages for this exception. Use the exception stack trace and error code to investigate the root cause of this exception. Root cause error code is JBO-25009. Error message parameters are {0=java.lang.Integer, 1=Data-Structure 1, 2=java.lang.String}
    at oracle.jbo.common.JboTypeMapEntries$1.convert(JboTypeMapEntries.java:124)
    at oracle.jbo.domain.TypeFactory.get(TypeFactory.java:892)
    at oracle.jbo.domain.TypeFactory.getInstance(TypeFactory.java:120)
    at oracle.jbo.domain.TypeFactory.convertToPrimitiveArray(TypeFactory.java:977)
    at oracle.jbo.domain.TypeFactory.get(TypeFactory.java:904)
    at oracle.jbo.domain.TypeFactory.getInstance(TypeFactory.java:120)
    at oracle.jbo.uicli.binding.JUCtrlListBinding.processNewInputValue(JUCtrlListBinding.java:4212)
    at oracle.adfinternal.view.faces.model.binding.FacesCtrlListBinding$ListValidator.validate(FacesCtrlListBinding.java:631)
    at oracle.adfinternal.view.faces.facelets.rich.JsfValidatorHandler$BindingValidator.validate(JsfValidatorHandler.java:122)
    at org.apache.myfaces.trinidad.component.UIXEditableValue.validateValue(UIXEditableValue.java:454)
    at org.apache.myfaces.trinidad.component.UIXSelectMany.validateValue(UIXSelectMany.java:95)
    at org.apache.myfaces.trinidad.component.UIXEditableValue.validate(UIXEditableValue.java:209)
    at org.apache.myfaces.trinidad.component.UIXEditableValue._executeValidate(UIXEditableValue.java:753)
    at org.apache.myfaces.trinidad.component.UIXEditableValue.processValidators(UIXEditableValue.java:349)
    at org.apache.myfaces.trinidad.component.UIXComponentBase.validateChildrenImpl(UIXComponentBase.java:1565)
    at org.apache.myfaces.trinidad.component.UIXComponentBase.validateChildren(UIXComponentBase.java:1550)
    at org.apache.myfaces.trinidad.component.UIXComponentBase.processValidators(UIXComponentBase.java:1307)
    at org.apache.myfaces.trinidad.component.UIXForm.processValidators(UIXForm.java:82)
    at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.execute(ExecuteThread.java:397)
    at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:346)
Caused by: java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "Data-Structure 1"
    at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:65)
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:580)
    at java.lang.Integer.valueOf(Integer.java:766)
    at oracle.jbo.common.JboTypeMapEntries$1.convert(JboTypeMapEntries.java:118)
    ... 74 more
## Detail 0 ##
java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "Data-Structure 1"
    at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:65)
```

Comment: So where is this cast happening exactly?

Comment: it seems problem is not related to the upper code but `home.xml` file

Comment: @luckydog32 No Cast is happening :(

Comment: @BarbarosÖzhan what could be the problem ?